# Is there a baseplate with connections on the bottom?

Tags: bricks-and-pieces

Today, I bought a baseplate ([10700](http://www.toysrus.com/buy/lego-bricks-more/lego-classic-green-baseplate-10700-6102278-45304716)). Sadly, the female connectors on the back are not "LEGO compatible"...you can't plug any LEGO bricks into them.  I want to build a LEGO cart so [dash can pull dot](https://www.makewonder.com/dash) (a big mechanical moving robot can pull a small nonmoving robot). I need to plug the wheels on the bottom of the large brick and a fence to block the little robot in on top. I listed all items in category Bricks on [Pick a Brick](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme) and found no match.  Similarly for [bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/).

Where can I find a large flat brick (at a minimum 4 inches by 4 inches) so I can build a wagon?

If all else fails, I can super glue some thin bricks together.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can certainly combine a number of LEGO parts to build the sort of element you are hoping for. If you want just one part to do this as simply as possible, I'd recommend a 16x16 plate:

[image]

This part is about 5 inches by 5 inches and has studs on top and antistuds underneath. You can find it on Bricklink:

http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=91405

There have also been some large bricks (up to 12x24) that might work for you:

[image: 12x24 brick]

Answer (score 12):

A baseplate does not have connectors on the bottom. The holes you see are simply an artifact of the forming process.

That said, it would be possible to build a scaffolding that supports a baseplate and keeps it "in system" with the surrounding bricks. A baseplate sitting (loosely) on top of the studs of another brick rests at the same height as a plate sitting on those bricks. So with three plates' height you can sandwich the baseplate in and attach it to something. This would allow you to secure the baseplate using the top studs and support it using the bottom of the scaffold. However, it should be noted that the baseplate is very flexible and won't support much weight in the middle without bending.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A baseplate is not the same as a plate.

A baseplate is meant as a base for your lego constructions, a plate can be used in a construction as well.

As for plates, I think 16x16 is the largest and 6x24 is the longest you can find.