# Can 2 baseplates be connected to make 2 story level?

Tags: building, bricks-and-pieces

My young girls are creating a house and want to connect baseplates to make a 2-story house. Is there a way? Are there specific pieces that can connect them?

Comment: Perhaps this question and answer can help you: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7367/is-there-a-baseplate-with-connections-on-the-bottom

Comment: Wdym? Do you mean that one baseplate is for the second floor while the other one is meant for the first? If so, you might see that you won't be able to build a way to get to the next floor (i.e. stairs or ladder). In this case, you should add another slim baseplate next to the first floor's baseplate and build the stairs or ladder on it to reach the next floor. But youll need some floor there, too. Just remember to make a hole so that they could get to the second floor! Oh, and obviously  you'll need some bricks to build the walls on the first floor, then you can attach the second floor on top

Comment: As Michael mentions, the following answer is probably the one you want: [A baseplate does not have connectors on the bottom](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/7373/56)

Comment: Well, only SOME baseplates don't have connectors on the bottom. It really depends on the size.

Comment: @mindstormsboi Can you name any that have connectors on the bottom? I think that's part of the definition. Ones that have connectors are known as plates.

Comment: They are quite small compared to the ones that don't have connectors on the bottom. Some are 4 by 4, 5 by 13, 4 by 11, y'know.